# get the path of my file to upload in grails

Tags: file, grails, gsp, grails-2.4

my view gsp   index.gsp

```
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main">
<title>Upload file and fullpath</title>
</head>
<div id="upload-data" class="content scaffold-create" role="main">
<div class="content scaffold-create" role="main">
    <h1>Upload file and full path</h1>
    <g:if test="${flash.message}"><div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div></g:if>
    <g:uploadForm action="fullpath">
        <fieldset class="form">
            <input type="file" name="file"  />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="buttons">
            <g:submitButton name="Upload" value="Upload" />
        </fieldset>
    </g:uploadForm>
</div>
```

my controller  Uploadfullpath

```
 package library

 class UploadfullpathController {

 def index() { }

 def fullpath(){

    def files = request.getFile('file')
    def fullpath=files.getProperties()
    System.out.println("full path is  : "+ fullpath)
 } 
 }
```

I need to get the full path of my file on my local disk for example ( c: /folder1/notes.txt ) or ( f : /folder2/note2.txt )**

Comment: Per HTML spec, the path is not included. Only the filename.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! . I need to get the full path of my file what would be the way .

Comment: You can't using the file input. If you need that the user will have to type it in separately.

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with the HTML specification only the name of the file is sent, not the entire path. Doing so would pose a leak of potentially sensitive or personally identifiable information.

If you need the full path you will have to have your users enter that manually as a separate piece of data. the `file` input won't give you this information, no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

You will get whole path by using originalFilename

```
def file = request.getFile('uploadFile')

println "FileName"+file.originalFilename
```

Output:

```
FileName C:\Users\BRACT-Admin\Downloads\vit.mp4
```